# Programmatically check if content is enabled in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit. I am exporting some pages and macros from my file to another Excel file and this works fine most of the time, however.... sometimes it does not work for the following reason: the destination file may not have "content enabled". When I open it, it displays the following message (see attached picture):

[image]

Is there any way to ***programmatically*** check for this issue before attempting the export? I need a way to check through VBA code.

Thank you.

Comment: See Options > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations. You can set which network paths are trusted and thus avoid this issue (in most cases).

Comment: Thank you Scott for suggesting this solution but the destination file can be anywhere in the network or locally and we have lots of users, each of them exporting to a different file and different location(s) that can change anytime... I was wondering if I can just use VBA to test

Comment: [here](http://www.devhut.net/2010/06/23/vbscript-createset-trusted-location-using-vbscript/) is something to look into and perhaps work with, although it does adjust Registry Settings, but may be a worthwhile solution to your issue.

Comment: Excellent, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks!